# Next Js create app JSS command

Tags: jss, nextjs

I tried both the below commands to create a `JSS next js` app but none of it has all the required files in the app.

```
npx create-sitecore-jss nextjs

npm init sitecore-jss nextjs
```

When I do `jss:build`, it says `src->temp->config.js` is missing and other serialized items are missing.

Can someone help me with the correct `next js jss` command to create an app?

I am using `JSS 20.0` version in `Sitecore 10.2 Containerized` instances.

Thanks,
Shakti

Comment: This is a very open-ended question that’s hard to answer in the StackExchange Q&A format.  My best suggestion for you is to review the JSS documentation to make sure you’re following the steps to create your NextJS app correctly.  https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/getting-started-with-jss-for-next-js-development.html

Comment: Look at the `package.json` - I believe you need to run `npm run build` with v20 of JSS.

Comment: @Shakti Patro Run jss setup and jss deploy config Out of these 2 commands should generate the src/temp/config for you.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on my local using these steps.

1. You need to run this command before creating your app.

   `npm install @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs`
2. Now use this command to create your app.

   `npx create-sitecore-jss nextjs`
3. This is what I get in the temp folder and also contains the `config.js` file that is missing at your end.

[image]
Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I have observed that if we run this command in Powershell, we see issues in some files missing but if we run it n command prompt, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ShaktiPatro Great. Please accept this question if you think it resolved your issue. Thanks